# Object array doesn't follow spiral path

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, path

I'm trying to create an array along this spiral, but I don't know why my object doesn't follow the path I created (I only modified the external line of the Blender curve spiral). It seems that the objects are following an offset path, but I don't understand why...

[image]

I use Blender 2.79 (downloaded 2 months ago) with Cycles Render

Comment: Have you applied transformations to the objects (Ctrl+A)? Do the both objects have the origin points placed in the same position?

Answer (score 3):

I placed the origin points in the same position and it worked. I didn't think the problem could be that easy. Thank you so much.